# Fetching Multiple Https request in Nodejs using ejs templates

Tags: node.js, ejs

Getting the first [ const p1] `HTTPS` request, but unable to fetch the second one [const p2] its showing me undefined.Where im missing

```
    function fetchJSON(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(url, function(err, res, body) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        reject(new Error('Failed with status code ' + res.statusCode));
      } else {
        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
      }
    });
  });
}


 router.get('/news-and-media',function(req,res,next){
    const p1 = fetchJSON('http://example.com/wsplus/abs/123');
    const p2 = fetchJSON('http://example.com/blsd/blog_posts/312');
  Promise.all([p1],[p2]).then((data) => {
  console.log(data[0]);                            // getting data 
  console.log(data[1]);                           // this giving me undefined
    res.render("news-and-media", { getdata: data[0],banner:data[1]} );
  }).catch(err => console.error('There was a problem', err));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use

```
Promise.all([p1], [p2])
```

but

```
Promise.all([p1, p2])
```

---

According to the [Promise.all() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which is saying :

> Promise.all(iterable);

Comment: yup its coming thanks @Gregory NEUT. But my doubt what the deference between them

Comment: In the first call of promise.all you gives to it two array that contains Promise. In the second call, you gives one array of Promise. The functions go through the array you gave as an argument and treat it.